# Using django-twilio package forgery protection is creating forbidden 403 error

Tags: python, django, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

I am using django-twilio package for forgery protection [django-twilio forgery protection docs](https://django-twilio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/decorators.html#how-forgery-protection-works)

I have a django texting app that is being used to both send automated messages directly through my cellphone messenger and also from my website while logged in. When DJANGO_TWILIO_FORGERY_PROTECTION = False, both platforms using my django texting app work.

When DJANGO_TWILIO_FORGERY_PROTECTION = True, only cellphone messenger works, and website gets 403 Forbidden.

**How can this be fixed while maintaining as much security as possible and keeping the same app as functional for both cellphone messenger and website.**

I know issue is to do with @twilio_view decorator

send-text.html

```
    <form action="{% url 'text-send' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="Body" required>
    <input type="submit" >
    </form>
```

Here is my texting app:

```
@twilio_view
def sendtext(request, reviewpk):
    if request.method == "POST":
        ACCOUNT_SID = settings.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID
        AUTH_TOKEN = settings.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
        client = Client(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)

        message_body = request.POST['Body']
        client.messages.create(
           to= "+13231342344",
           from_="+14571342764",
           body=message_body
         )
        return confirm_things(request)

def confirm_things(request):  
    if 'HTTP_X_TWILIO_SIGNATURE' in request.META:
        resp = MessagingResponse()
        resp.message("good job message was sent")
        return HttpResponse(str(resp), content_type='text/xml')          
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard'))
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('textsend/', views.sendtext, name='text-send'),
    path('dashboard/', views.dash, name='dash'),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

`DJANGO_TWILIO_FORGERY_PROTECTION = True` should only be used for requests that are webhooks coming from Twilio.

You should authenticate your user form submission with your regular session (or whatever) authentication as well as the existing CSRF protection. Basically, you shouldn't be using `@twilio_view` for any controller action that is not responding to Twilio.

Comment: makes sense. In that case I will separate out submission from website into a different app and use standard django authentication. How about if I ping the twilio number by sending an sms from my personal cell phone, is that also considered as a webhook coming from Twilio?

Comment: If you send a message to the Twilio number then it will make an HTTP request (webhook) to the URL you specify, so yes.

Answer (score 0):

Try including @csrf_exempt decorator

Import it
`from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt`

And then in the function

```
@csrf_exempt
@twilio_view
def sendtext(request, reviewpk):
    if request.method == "POST":
        ACCOUNT_SID = settings.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID
        AUTH_TOKEN = settings.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
        client = Client(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)

        message_body = request.POST['Body']
        client.messages.create(
           to= "+13231342344",
           from_="+14571342764",
           body=message_body
         )
        return confirm_things(request)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This does not resolve issue, @twilio_view already has CSRF exempt packaged into that decorator.

Comment: The why is `{% csrf_token %}` is present in the form ?